# How can I define an instance of a typeclass in scala that can be used for all subclasses of a particular type?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass, scala-cats

I am trying to define an instance of `Show` (from cats 0.9) that can be used for all members of an ADT as follows:

```
import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats:0.9.0`, cats.Show

sealed abstract class Colour(val name: String)

implicit val ColourShow = new Show[Colour] {
  def show(c: Colour) = c.name
}

object Colour {
  object Red extends Colour("Red")
  object Blue extends Colour("Blue")
}

import Show._

println(Colour.Red.show)
```

An applicable instance cannot be found for `Red`, however:

```
Compiling /Users/Rich/Projects/worksheets/fp-patterns/Colours.sc
/Users/Rich/Projects/worksheets/fp-patterns/Colours.sc:16: value show is not a member of object ammonite.$file.Colours.Colour.Red
val res_5 = println(Colour.Red.show)
                               ^
Compilation Failed
```

Is it possible to use typeclasses in this way? I am trying to avoid having to define a separate instance for each concrete instanct of Colour.

Comment: Try `(Colour.Red: Colour).show`

Comment: This still gives `Compiling /Users/Rich/Projects/worksheets/fp-patterns/Colours.sc
/Users/Rich/Projects/worksheets/fp-patterns/Colours.sc:16: value show is not a member of ammonite.$file.Colours.Colour
val res_5 = println((Colour.Red: Colour).show)
                                         ^
Compilation Failed`

Comment: `import cats.implicits._`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mistaking what's happening here. The implicit you've defined does actually work for the instances.

eg.

```
ColourShow.show(Colour.Red)
```

If you want to be able to call show() on an instance of a Colour, without any arguments, you'll need to provide a definition of a trait that has a method show, which takes no arguments, and an implicit conversion from Colour to that trait.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what people have pointed out, you'll need to import `import cats.implicits._`

see a working example in: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/d1egoaz/LVaJEccDSeas9VmzHqf1ug/1

You can also use the shorter version to create a `Show` instance for `Colour`:

```
implicit val colourShow: Show[Colour] = Show.show[Colour](_.name)
```

Comment: Am I right that the `cats.implicits._` import is only needed if we don't define our own instance of `Show`?

Comment: not sure :/ might want to ask on the cats gitter channel https://gitter.im/typelevel/cats